# emberjs getting login state onload

Tags: ember.js

So i've setup a simple login system on the backend. Login & logout functionality works, but im trying to get the state management going. I have the following state manager:

```
App.loginStateManager = Ember.StateManager.create({
  initialState: "unknown",
  loggedIn: Ember.State.create({}),
  loggedOut: Ember.State.create({}),
  unknown: Ember.State.create({
    enter: function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/loginstate",
        type: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
          if(data == "loggedin") {
            LocalBookFinder.loginStateManager.transitionTo("loggedIn");
          }
          else {
            LocalBookFinder.loginStateManager.transitionTo("loggedOut");
          }
        }
      });
    }
  })
});
```

The reason i start at "unknown" as supposed to loggedOut, is because on the page load, I want to query the server to find out if the user already has a session or not. So that's what the ajax logic is there for. Now, the state does update appropriately, but because my view has already loaded, it shows me the logged in/register links. Is there a way i can bind the state to the application template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to set a property on the application controller and have a conditional in the the application template.  This will be bound automatically so you can then set the property on the application controller in your success function and the UI should update accordingly.

```
{{#if controller.loginState }} 
  Show something 
{{ else }} 
  so not ready loading... 
{{/if}}
```

Then something like this in your controller.

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({ 
  .... 
  loginState: null 
});
```

Comment: This got me on the right path. I removed the use of a statemanager completely. I moved the ajax request into the ApplicationRoute setupController method. In there i simply call controller.set("loginState", result). And in the template, use controller.loginState as you suggested. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Great!!  That is actually more like how I am handling it in one of my applications.

Comment: I like the simplicity. A login state manager kind of makes sense, but updating those appropriately is a bit daunting as well, and maybe even overkill for something like this.